# Server Error When Updating ExpressionEngine

Tags: expressionengine

After updating ExpressionEngine, from 2.3.1 to 2.5.3, clicking on Add-ons > Fieldtypes returns a server error. I used the Updater add-on to run the updates. Has anyone had this issue before? If so, how did you remedy it?

Comment: if you update EE the traditional way do you get the same error?

Comment: I am not sure. I did not attempt to update the traditional way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just run into this issue. The library for fieldtypes which a few third party fieldtype modules depend on has been moved as of 2.4. You'll need to scan through any third party field type addons and manually update them. Here's a quick list of modules I have had to update

Matrix
Wygwam
Google Mx
Solspace Calendar
Favorites (solspace)

Comment: Patrick, can you please give an example of how you updated Matrix?